# Mobile Push: What's stored inside of the TimeInApp value in the Push Message Detail report

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, mobilepush

The [Push Message Detail](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_push_message_detailed_report.htm&type=5) report includes a `TimeinApp` field which is described as:

> How long the user spent in the app after opening the message. Measured
> from the time the subscriber opens the app to the time the app goes
> into the background

Since our MobilePush SDKs are not migrated to versions 8.*, I can't see any data in the exported CSV file, but I need to prepare a data extension to capture this value

Could anyone provide more detail about the data that can be obtained with this field? I'm mostly interested in knowing the following:

- is it a numeric field?
- if yes, what is the unit of time here?
- does it only count the time spent when the app is in focus (really opened) and not working in the background?

Comment: This field has existed since, at least, version 3 of the SDK. Version 8 is not required for this value to be populated.

Comment: @BillMote I forgot that tracking is not implemented properly yet. Getting the SDK to version 8. will happen first for us. Do you know the other details about this field? What data type is it and what's the unit of time?

Comment: Tracking has been implemented properly since, at least, 2014.